# My App doesn't install on Android 11, but works in older versions

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-11

I have an issue where I just updated my device to android 11 last night and my app doesn't seem to install on android 11. reverts back to the install button even after trying to complete the install.
Any idea what I could be doing wrong?
this is a snippet from my build.gradle :

```
 compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId  "myapp.android"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 44
        versionName "1.1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
```

Comment: Are you installing a debug build, or is it a store version? If you build it you should get some error logs about why it's failing

Comment: Post the log as well. Otherwise it's kinda hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: I am building the play store build. Debug versions seem to work, just release versions have an issue. is there an easy way to get device logs?

Comment: You should see what logging methods you use. If you use `Timber` library, you can set it to show logs. They can be obfuscated if you use R8 (ProGuard).

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading you gradle.

after that File -> Invalidate caches and Restart you Android studio.

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
```

in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```